# Access to derived class variable in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to access a variable inside derived class.

```
     printf("%c", God.m_Please.me);
```

Inside God class declaration I have declared m_Please as

```
     private:
     Please *m_Please
```

and helpme is a variable declared in a class derived from Please

```
    class Help : public Please
```

and me is defined as

```
    unsigned char me[1000];
```

when I try to compile this I get error

```
error C2228: left of '.me' must have class/struct/union type
```

I am Using Visual Studio 6.0

Please reply back....

orward declare "class Please;" before God – wqking 
That helped to remove the first error :) but I still get 2 other errors

Thanks,

Comment: Wow, is this an HTML5-C++ extension? :)

Comment: Did u forget `;` in `Please *m_Please` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Please* Please` is *private*. You cannot access a private member from a derived class. It must be *protected*.

```
class Please{
  protected:
  Please* m_Please;
  int pplHelped;
};

class Help : public Please {

  void whatever(){
      //assume m_Please was initialized elsewhere
      Please::m_Please->pplHelped; //do something with pplHelped
  }
};
```

If you are trying to access the base member variable through an instance of the derived class, it should be declared *public* in the base class.

```
class Please{
  public:
  Please* m_Please; //init this somewhere
  int pplHelped;
};

class Help : public Please{
};

void somefunc(){
  Help God;
  //assume m_Please was initialized in Constructor
  printf("%d\n", God.m_Please->pplHelped;
}
```

Comment: ok what if int pplHelped is declared and used inside Help...how should I access that...

Comment: @user2829 You mean like `class Help : public Please{ int pplHelped };`? The same rules apply. If you want to access it from the outside, make it _public_. If it's for inside use only, use _private_ or _protected_.

Answer (score 1):

`m_Please` is a pointer (`Please*`). You cannot use operator `.` on pointers.

The correct way to do it would be

```
printf("%c",God.m_Please->me);
```

Comment: error C2248: 'm_Please' cannot access private member declared in class 'God'.error C2027: use of undefined type 'Please'.C2227: left of '->me' must point to class/struct/union.....please do reply

Answer (score 0):

God.m_Please->me
-> instead .
m_Please is a pointer

Comment: error C2248: 'm_Please' cannot access private member declared in class 'God'.error C2027: use of undefined type 'Please'.C2227: left of '->me' must point to class/struct/union.....please do reply –

Comment: As Vilx said, you need to declare "me" as protected instead of private.

Comment: still get same errors... not it says cannot access protected members of God Class use of undefined type 'Please' and C2227: left of '->me' must point to class/struct/union.....please do reply

Comment: forward declare "class Please;" before God

Comment: That helped to remove the first error :) but i still get 2 other errors

Answer (score 0):

`God.m_Please.me` is inreconcilable with `PLease *m_Please`.  As `m_Please` is a pointer, use `God.m_Please->me`.  Still, that provides access to the character array, so you either need to specify which character in the array `printf()` should display (e.g. `me[0]`), or use the `printf` format `"%s"` which can display ASCIIZ strings.

Answer (score 0):

You're syntax is confusing. A complete sample code would be appreciated.

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to access a private class member from a derived class. That won't work unless the derived class is declared as a friend to the base class. The proper way would be to use `protected` instead of `private`.

Oh, and as others suggested, use `->` instead of `.` for accessing members of a pointer.

Comment: error C2248: 'm_Please' cannot access private member declared in class 'God'.error C2027: use of undefined type 'Please'.C2227: left of '->me' must point to class/struct/union.....please do reply –

Comment: @user2829 - you can edit your own question and add such information there. Also, please provide a complete sample program. The pieces you have given are not enough.